# chi squared divergence and Kullback Leibler divergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\def\KL#1#2{\operatorname{KL}(#1 \| #2)}$
$\def\chisq#1#2{\operatorname{\chi^2}(#1 \| #2)}$

I am asked to prove that given two discrete random variables (or probability measures) $P \ll Q$ i.e. $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$ (so that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is just $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where defined. We will call this $g(x)$), we have $\KL P Q \leq \chisq P Q$ where both are defined.

The definitions are:

- $\KL P Q  = \mathbb E_Q[g(x) \ln g(x)]$, and
- $\chisq P Q = \mathbb E_Q[(g(x) - 1)^2]$.

Now, one way of proving the inequality is to show $(y-1)^2 \geq y \ln y$ everywhere on $[0,\infty)$, since this is the range of $g$. However, this is not true, for example with $y = 2$.

So this makes me wonder if what I have got is wrong. Is it not possible that I can find $P$ and $Q$ such that $g$ is supported in  the region where the inequality above does not hold, so that I can get a counterexample?

I know I am doing something very wrong here, something very silly. I would like to be pointed out what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: For what it's worth, to can prove the slightly stronger inequality KL $\leq \log(1+\chi^2)$. See, e.g., (plug alert!) Lemma B.5 in the appendix of my survey: https://ccanonne.github.io/survey-topics-dt.html (PDF: https://ccanonne.github.io/files/misc/main-survey-fnt.pdf )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything "wrong" *per se*. When proving inequalities among [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence), you sometimes need to add a multiple of $\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}Q}-1$ to get functions you can relate via elementary means. In this case, I believe the relevant identities are

$$y\ln y - y + 1 = (y-1)^2\int_0^1\frac{t\,\mathrm{d}t}{t+(1-t)y}\text{,}$$
which is the integral-remainder form of Taylor's theorem for the function $y\ln y - y+1$ about $y=1$ through first order, and
$$0\leq \frac{t}{t+(1-t)y} \leq 1\text{,}$$
which is elementary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, if I put $g(x) = y$ above and integrate on both sides, then the left side is the KL divergence, while the right hand side is less than or equal to the $\chi^2$ divergence. Very smart! $+1$ and an acceptance from my side.

Comment: Also, I think that it is possible to prove that $y\ln y -y + 1 \leq (y-1)^2$ on $(0,\infty)$ by mere differential calculus. But the key idea was the addition of $\frac{dP}{dQ} - 1$ : it sort of simplified things very well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof, using $\ln(1+u) \leq u$ for $u>-1$, i.e., $\ln x = \ln(1+(x-1)) \leq x-1$ for all $x>0$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_Q[g(x)\ln g(x)] &\leq 
\mathbb{E}_Q[g(x)(g(x)-1)]
= \mathbb{E}_Q[g(x)^2 -1] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_Q[(g(x)-1)^2]
+ \underbrace{2(\mathbb{E}_Q[g(x)]-1)}_{(\star)}
\end{align}$$
and the second term $(\star)$ is $0$ because, by definition of $g$ as the Radon—Nikodym derivative,
$$
\mathbb{E}_Q[g(x)] = \mathbb{E}_P[1] = 1.
$$

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the comment and the answer. I'll make sure to look at your document when I get the time. Thanks once again.